# How to get vino to run after autologin on a headless server - Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: headless, vino

I have a server I prepped here in the office and got everything working.
I set up auto-login followed by an immediate lock-screen so that vino would start automatically after a reboot.
I took the rack out to an ISP to COLO the server, -without- a monitor/keyboard/mouse, and everything still works except vino does not start up now that it is headless. Auto-login is still working. `w` shows:

```
mylogin      :0       :0               14:32   ?xdm?  41.02s  0.01s /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubu
```

But nothing in the listeners for vino-server. `netstat -anp` shows:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1496/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3314/apache2        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1309/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6582/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2722/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3314/apache2        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9632          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1894/xinetd
```

I'd like to make it possible to turn vino-server on and off at will via the command line like we've done in the past with VNC server. My plan was to use `ufw` to firewall/un-firewall port 5900 as needed - so just getting vino-server running would solve my problem.

I tried running `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0` from a secure shell session, but it appears that only works from session with access to DBUS. - Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found it here: `https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vino#Running_on_a_headless_server`

Just had to create `~/.config/autostart/vino-server.desktop` with this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Vino VNC server
Exec=/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
NoDisplay=true
```

And then reboot the server.

Comment: In case anyone landed here on another distro, this is the dummy video driver you need:
Arch: `xf86-video-dummy`
Debian: `xserver-xorg-video-dummy`
RedHat: `xorg-x11-drv-dummy`